# Appium & Xcode 9: UI testing in safari view controller not possible anymore?

Tags: ios, xcode9, appium-ios, sfsafariviewcontroller, uitest

Is there any way I can automate ui tests in safari view controller? Since I'm using Xcode 9 I cannot reference UI elements inside fo SFSafariViewController anymore. When I debug the view hierarchy, I cannot see any XCUIElements, for example UITextFields in order to perform an automated login. In Xcode 8, I could access those elements via XCUIPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a workaround:
https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-automate-ui-tests-for-safari-view-controller/6551/6?u=doge